# Como fazer com que o meu programa leia somente as linhas novas de um arquivo que atualiza a cada momento em Python

Tags: python, api

Tenho um arquivo que atualiza a cada momento(um log de erros) e cada log dele é uma linha que vai aumentando o arquivo, mas não sei como fazer pro meu programa ler somente as linhas novas. (meu código lê o arquivo a cada 1min)

Precisaria armazenar a quantidade de linhas do arquivo que foi lido, e quando ler o arquivo novo atualizado, ler a quantidade de linhas e diminuir a quantidade de linhas do arquivo lido anteriormente e colocar o código pra ler somente as linhas dessa diferença.

Sei que ficou um pouco difícil de explicar mas quem puder, me da ajuda pq eu não consegui pensar uma forma de fazer isso.

Comment: Tem diversas formas de fazer isso dependendo de tipo de informação é salva. Poderia ser por timestamp do erro, id do erro, quantidade de linhas como vocês mesmo disse. Para que possamos ajudá-lo seria interessante você nos dar mais informações do seu problema e como você já tentou resolvê-lo.

Comment: Tenho um arquivo de logs, que atualiza a cada segundo, e estou fazendo um código que lê esse arquivo e procura linhas que contenham erros, mas não quero que ele leia os mesmos logs de erro todas as vezes, apenas os novos que apareceram recentemente. Mas não sei como fazer isso

Comment: Você não vai conseguir fugir muito disso a menos que tenha informações que possam ser relevantes em cada linha como eu disse no comentário anterior como um timestamp ou um id e mesmo assim vc vai ter q ler esse campo da linha para identificar se ele é uma linha valida para a leitura ou não.